# Django query filter combining AND and OR with Q objects don't return the expected results

Tags: python, django, django-q

I try to combine AND and OR in a filter using Q objects. It looks like that the | behave like an AND. This is related to the previous annotate which is run in the same query and not as a subquery.

What is the correct way to handle this with Django?

**models.py**

```
class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=100)
    stock = models.BooleanField(_('in stock'), default=True)
    hide = models.BooleanField(_('hide'), default=False)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(_('deleted'), default=False)

class Item(models.Model):
    barcode = models.CharField(_('barcode'), max_length=100, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(_('quantity'), default=1)
    type = models.ForeignKey('Type', related_name='items', verbose_name=_('type'))
```

**views.py**

```
def hire(request):
    categories_list = Category.objects.all().order_by('sorting')
    types_list = Type.objects.annotate(quantity=Sum('items__quantity')).filter(
        Q(hide=False) & Q(deleted=False),
        Q(stock=False) | Q(quantity__gte=1))
    return render_to_response('equipment/hire.html', {
           'categories_list': categories_list,
           'types_list': types_list,
           }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**resulting SQL query**

```
SELECT "equipment_type"."id" [...] FROM "equipment_type" LEFT OUTER JOIN
    "equipment_subcategory" ON ("equipment_type"."subcategory_id" =
    "equipment_subcategory"."id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "equipment_item" ON
    ("equipment_type"."id" = "equipment_item"."type_id") WHERE 
    ("equipment_type"."hide" = False AND "equipment_type"."deleted" = False )
    AND ("equipment_type"."stock" = False )) GROUP BY "equipment_type"."id"
    [...] HAVING SUM("equipment_item"."quantity") >= 1
```

**expected SQL query**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    equipment_type
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT type_id, SUM(quantity) AS qty
    FROM equipment_item
    GROUP BY type_id
) T1
ON id = T1.type_id
WHERE hide=0 AND deleted=0 AND (T1.qty > 0 OR stock=0)
```

---

**EDIT**: I added the expected SQL query (without the join on equipment_subcategory)

Comment: looks like an error to me. i'd file a bug report or ask on #django

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, no success here or on #django. So I choose to use a raw SQL query to solve this problem...

Here the working code:

```
types_list = Type.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM equipment_type
    LEFT JOIN (                                            
        SELECT type_id, SUM(quantity) AS qty               
        FROM equipment_item                                
        GROUP BY type_id                                   
    ) T1                                                   
    ON id = T1.type_id                                     
    WHERE hide=0 AND deleted=0 AND (T1.qty > 0 OR stock=0) 
    ')
```

Answer (score 61):

Try adding parentheses to explicitly specify your grouping?  As you already figured out, multiple params to [filter()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter-kwargs) are just joined via AND in the underlying SQL.

Originally you had this for the filter:

```
[...].filter(
    Q(hide=False) & Q(deleted=False),
    Q(stock=False) | Q(quantity__gte=1))
```

If you wanted (A & B) & (C | D) then this should work:

```
[...].filter(
    Q(hide=False) & Q(deleted=False) &
    (Q(stock=False) | Q(quantity__gte=1)))
```

Comment: I also tried this solution, but it still don't handle the request correctly. Given the documentation at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects, filter(Q&Q).filter(Q|Q) or filter(Q&Q, Q|Q) or filter(Q&Q&(Q|Q)) should all behave the same way. And I my case, it's the wrong way...

Comment: Have you tried it with something that is not added via annotate()?  The documentation for the AND and OR logic for filter() and exclude() is not bullet proof so keep inspecting the actual queries.  The documentation shows the OR'd clauses in the SQL but I do not see that with 1.2.3 and sqlite3.  I do see it when I do Qa & Qb & (Qc | Qd).

Answer (score 15):

This answer is late but could be helpful to a lot of people out there.

```
[...].filter(hide=False & deleted=False)
.filter(Q(stock=False) | Q(quantity__gte=1))
```

This will generate something similar to

```
WHERE (hide=0 AND deleted=0 AND (T1.qty > 0 OR stock=0))
```

Comment: .. and gals, too.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my example of complicated query, I hope you find it helpful

```
or_condition = Q()
and_condition = Q(company=request.user.profile.company)

for field in MyModel._meta.get_fields():
    if field.name != 'created_on' and field.name != 'company':
        or_condition.add(
            Q(**{"{}__icontains".format(field.name): query}), Q.OR)

and_condition.add(or_condition2, Q.AND)
MyModel.objects.filter(and_condition)
```

The problem with this method is that you get an `empty (AND: )` case in your `or_condition`. It doesn't affect the query at all, but it annoys me!
My current solution is as follows

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

and_condition = Q(company=request.user.profile.company)
or_condition = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(**{"{}__icontains".format(field.name): query})
                                     for field in MyModel._meta.get_fields() if field.name != 'created_on' and field.name != 'company'))

and_condition.add(or_condition, Q.AND)
MyModel.objects.filter(and_condition)
```