# search with 2 field in generic api view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Do you know how can I search with 2 fields with 'and' conditions?
I mean in the below code I need to search'search_fields' with symbol name and time_frame,(both conditions together not only one of them)

```
class RegisterSymbolViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = SymbolValidationSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['^symbol','^time_frame']
    queryset = RegisterSymbol.objects.all()
```

Comment: You can use the Django Q queries with 'and'/'or'. This would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986071/django-query-filter-combining-and-and-or-with-q-objects-dont-return-the-expecte

Comment: yes, I tried to use it but I don't have a specific symbol, the symbol is whatever the user requests, for example, if the user wants BTC price symbol is BTC and if wants another thing, the symbol is another thing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all DRF docs say that only text-based fields can be used as search field so if timeframe is DateField it will most likely not work.

```
The SearchFilter class will only be applied if the view has a 
search_fields attribute set. The search_fields attribute should 
be a list of names of text type fields on the model, 
such as CharField or TextField.
```

You can try creating custom SearchFilter class and override `filter_queryset`method to use `and` instead of `or` operator.

See DRF source code
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/86673a337a4fe8861c090b4532379b97e3921fef/rest_framework/filters.py#L123